# A Question on Class Groups

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am perhaps being silly and the answer is obvious but I will ask anyhow:

For an algebraic number field $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ we have the group of fractional ideals $I_K$ and the subgroup of principal ideals $P_K$, the norm map $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}$ naturally extends to $I_K$ and as such to $P_K$. I must have forgotten an important point in class field theory but just for a refresh:

What is $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(I_K)/N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(P_K)$?

Comment: How does the norm extend to a class of ideals?

Comment: What is $I_K$ exactly? Do you mean the group of all fractional ideals, or the ideal class group? I assume the former, as "principal ideal class" doesn't make much sense in the ideal class group: it's simply the identity element. I edited your question, please check if that matches your intention - otherwise just rollback.

Comment: Class field theory won't be of much help here.

Comment: Yes Yes, fractional ideals thank you.

To comment further about this question it is possible to show that this group is a factor group of the class group $Cl_K$ and that it is annihilated by $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$ . I suppose the remainder of my question would be whether or not it is the largest such factor group.